# Asignar variable a NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo el siguiente INSERT en el que me gustaría asignar a valor "NULL" sin una variable es '0' para evitar tener que hacer un update manual

```
UPDATE tb_01 SET percent_usage = NULL WHERE percent_usage = 0;
```

Como puedo adaptar la query para que me tome en cuenta esta causistica?

```
INSERT INTO tb_01 (`time`,`hostname`,`percent_usage`) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('$DATE','%d%m%Y%H%i'),@@hostname,'$percent_usage_real') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE time = STR_TO_DATE('$DATE','%d%m%Y%H%i'), percent_usage = '$percent_usage_real'"
```

Gracias!

Comment: Conviene que resuelvas esto a nivel de SQL directamente, sea en la configuración de la tabla. Me parece (no lo he probado) que si declaras el campo como `DEFAULT NULL` cuando insertas un `0` te lo guarda como `NULL`, dependiendo del tipo de dato que sea. Haz una prueba y, si no lo hace entonces lo más simple sería crear un `TRIGGER` del tipo `AFTER INSERT` el cual, cuando los valores para ese campo sean igual a `0` te los cambie por `NULL`. Las bases de datos tienen herramientas potentes para resolver este tipo de cosas sin necesidad de delegarlas a ningún lenguaje.

Comment: voy a probar lo del DEFAULT NULL

Comment: no ha funcionado. Si el valor vale "0" me pone un "0". Para evitar poner un TRIGGER, no puedo poner algun case dentro del insert?

Comment: Si no quieres hacer un `TRIGGER` lo más simple es que verifiques el valor antes de insertarlo, de modo que cuando sea `0` lo cambies por `NULL`, algo así: `$elValor = ($elValor==0 || $elValor =="0") ? NULL: $elValor;` haciendo eso, cuando sea `0` o `'0'` te lo cambiará a `NULL` y entonces luego haces la inserción. Pero un `TRIGGER` sigue siendo lo mejor.

Comment: eso he hecho. Gracias!